# Cannot import multisignature descriptor in Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, multi-signature, bitcoin-cli, output-script-descriptors

I created a multisignature address in regtest:

```sh
ADDR_1=`bitcoin-cli getnewaddress "" "bech32"`
ADDR_2=`bitcoin-cli getnewaddress "" "bech32"`
PB1=$(bitcoin-cli -named getaddressinfo address=$ADDR_1 | jq -r '.pubkey')
PB2=$(bitcoin-cli -named getaddressinfo address=$ADDR_2 | jq -r '.pubkey')
ADDR_P2SH_P2WPKH_NATIVE_2=`bitcoin-cli -named createmultisig nrequired=1 keys='''["'$PB1'","'$PB2'"]''' address_type="bech32" | jq -r '.address'`
```

After that, I generated 101 blocks:

`bitcoin-cli generatetoaddress 101 $ADDR_P2SH_P2WPKH_NATIVE_2`

Then, I wanted to retrieve the listunspent:

`bitcoin-cli listunspent 1 101 '["'$ADDR_P2SH_P2WPKH_NATIVE_2'"]'`

However, it returned an empty result. So, I attempted to import the new address using addr():

```
CHECKSUM=$(bitcoin-cli getdescriptorinfo "addr($ADDR_P2SH_P2WPKH_NATIVE_2)" | jq -r .checksum)
bitcoin-cli importdescriptors '[{ "desc": "addr('$ADDR_P2SH_P2WPKH_NATIVE_2')#'"$CHECKSUM"'", "timestamp": "now", "internal": true }]'
```

This resulted in an error:

```json
[
  {
    "success": false,
    "error": {
      "code": -4,
      "message": "Cannot import descriptor without private keys to a wallet with private keys enabled"
    }
  }
]
```

I also tried:

```sh
CHECKSUM=$(bitcoin-cli getdescriptorinfo "wsh(multi(1,$PB1,$PB2))" | jq -r .checksum)
bitcoin-cli importdescriptors '[{ "desc": "wsh(multi(1,'$PB1','$PB2'))#'"$CHECKSUM"'", "timestamp": "now", "internal": true }]'
```

But encountered the same result.

Another attempt is

```
bitcoin-cli -named createwallet wallet_name="bia" disable_private_keys=true
CHECKSUM=$(bitcoin-cli getdescriptorinfo "wsh(multi(1,$PB1,$PB2))" | jq -r .checksum)
bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet=bia importdescriptors '[{ "desc": "wsh(multi(1,'$PB1','$PB2'))#'"$CHECKSUM"'", "timestamp": "now", "internal": true }]'
bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet=bia listunspent 1 101 '["'$ADDR_P2SH_P2WPKH_NATIVE_2'"]'
```

it's still empty

Comment: You're passing `"timestamp": "now"`, implying that the address was only created now, so no rescanning of history will take place. You need to either explicitly rescan, or set the timestamp to a value before the first transaction to that address took place.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I need to create a new wallet and use -rpcwallet ? Because with other method I get the error about private keys

Comment: With descriptor wallets there doesn't exist a distinction between watch-only addresses and full addresses in the wallet anymore. Instead, the whole wallet is either watch-only or full.

Comment: you are right I can scan before mine the blocks and I can find UTXO available, but I need to create a new wallet with `disable_private_keys=true`? Only my last attempt work. in that way I will have a problem during the `signrawtransactionwithwallet`

Comment: If you want to be able to sign you'll need to have the descriptor with private keys imported.

Comment: yes, but I can retrieve the Private key if I use `getnewaddress`? I can't use `dumpprivkey` anymore. I'd like to use only Bitcoin-cli not an external tool

Comment: You can use `listdescriptors` to get the xprv of a wallet (set the flag to get private keys) and use those. You shouldn't need `createmultisig` anymore. Descriptor wallets generally don't have/use WIF keys anymore, unless you import them.

Comment: "You shouldn't need createmultisig anymore" because I should use `wsh(multi)` descriptor after retrieving the Xpriv -> Private key?

Comment: Yes, descriptors can do everything `createmultisig` can (and far more).

Comment: Okay, thanks. So, if I want to use a multi-signature address, I need to create the multi using private keys and descriptor instead of using createmultisig if I also want to sign the transaction.

Comment: There is even documentation on that topic: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/multisig-tutorial.md

Comment: Thanks Pieter, I followed the tutorial and it works. Understand a lot of new things. Thanks again for your time